# ImageURL returns empty after loading the image using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a DataList with ImageButtons on my page. I am loading the images in the ImageButtons using JQuery. It works fine. But when I try to cycle through the DataList to get the ImageURL for the ImageButtons, I get nothing.

Do I need to use any other method to get the URL of the images? I am loading the images using the following JQuery:

```
img.attr("src", photo.find("URL").text());
```

I think I did not provide enough details for the question. I am working on ASP.NET and VB.

I have a DataList on my webform, which has ImageButtons. I am loading the images in these ImageButtons using JQuery (the code line above). I want to get the ImageURL from my VB code when the user clicks on an ImageButton. But all I am getting is an empty string.

The HTML for the ImageButton is:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Url")%>' CssClass="image" OnClick="img_Click" />
```

And img_Click function in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub img_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim img As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)
    Dim str As String = img.ImageUrl
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post how are you trying to get the ImageURL?

Comment: For i = 0 To dlPhotos.Items.Count - 1
      Dim str As String = CType(dlPhotos.Items(i).FindControl("img"), ImageButton).ImageUrl
Next

Comment: That too me looks like VBScript, and you are querying for ImageURL. When you set the image with jQuery you set the SRC attribute of the image, not the ImageURL., from this much cannot figure out what you actually try to accomplish. Try to set up a fiddler or post the complete code....

Comment: I am setting the SRC attribute in JQuery because I cannot set ImageURL attribute via JQuery.

Comment: If you do set the src, you will need to look for the src attribute in your VBScript as well. I'm still confused why are you mixing jQuery (which is a Javascript extension) with VBScript.... the 2 don't really marry up....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Get ImageUrl of a asp image control whose image is set by jquery in the client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528497/how-to-get-imageurl-of-a-asp-image-control-whose-image-is-set-by-jquery-in-the-c)